# Wget - Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority on Ubuntu 18

Tags: command-line, server, ssl, wget, aws

I have some tar.gz and zip files on my website. The website is hosted on aws (ubuntu 18). But Users can't download them using wget. It is giving this error while running :-

```
wget https://example.com/downloads/abc.tar.gz
```

I've kept the website name example.com for privacy.

```
Resolving abc.com (example.com)...
Connecting to example.com (example.com):443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify example.com's certificate, issued by ‘CN=Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA,O=Sectigo Limited,L=Salford,ST=Greater Manchester,C=GB’: Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to example.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

curl is not working either

```
    curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle" of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented 
in the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate
 (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

Comment: It is not clear what the problem is just from this output and without having the real URL for more checks. But I recommend that you check the site with [SSLLabs](https://ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html). It is likely a broken setup, like failure to provide the intermediate certificates in your configuration ("chain issues" in the SSLLabs report).

Answer (score 0):

**Solved!**

The problem was with apache config.
There was no conf defined for example.com

As soon as I fixed the conf. It started working.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).